# Hostname of machine changed unexpectedly to mongodb after reboot

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, hostname, mongodb

I have mongodb 3.0.4 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and after I did a reboot I noticed that the hostname changed to `mongodb`.
Indeed I see `myuser@mongodb` instead of `myuser@myhostname` as it was before the reboot.
Again by running `cat /etc/hostname` I get `mongodb`.
And if I try to change it back again by running `sudo hostname myhostname` it shows this error `sudo: unable to resolve host mongodb`. This error shows up whenever I run `sudo [anything]`. I tried another reboot but this didn't fix the problem.

How to fix this? And why did this occur in the first place?
BTW the reboot was done after chaning default `ulimit` fildes number.

Comment: how did you install `mongodb` (the version is 2.4.9 in the repos so what source did you use etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 places where the hostname values is set, you can edit them both manually with

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

That shouldn't give you any errors, then reboot

Comment: But why did this happen in the first place?

Comment: I don't know why it happened.

Comment: editing `mongodb` in `/etc/hostname` to `myhostname` + rebooting worked, thanks. But why this happened remains a mistery...